# How can a 2D texture on a plane be displaced with a GLSL shader with three.js?

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl

Lets say we have a simple `PlaneBufferGeometry` with a texture applied like the one below:

[image: input image]

Knowing that the material will use a `ShaderMaterial`, what operation would need to happen for the texture to be rendered like this **by morphing from the first state to the resulting state** by some sort of uProgress/uTime uniform provided to the fragment shader?

[image: distortion expectations]

I'm hoping that by starting to write this kind of manipulations in glsl I will be able to implement more advanced effects (like a 2D fire animation).

Comment: Thanks for sharing @Rabbid76. The example you showed has hundreds of lines of unexplained code. I'm looking for the basic steps first in order to understand that effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from @pailhead answer I was able to create the final animation code as follows:

Apart from the basic uniforms and attributes passed by three.js we also pass the time (since starting the animation loop) and a uMap which is the texture loaded with the texture loader and exposed as a uniform

The vertex shader is basic. It just passes the uv position to the fragment shader:

varying vec2 vUv;

```
void main() {
  vUv = uv;  
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position,1.0);
}
```

In the fragment shader we use a sin function to variate the displacement in such a way that it 'circles around' to the initial position and also goes on the negative side.

```
varying vec2 vUv;

uniform float uTime;
uniform sampler2D uMap;

void main() {
  vec4 map = texture2D(uMap, vec2(vUv.x + (vUv.y - 0.5) * sin(uTime * 0.01), vUv.y) );
  gl_FragColor = vec4( map.rgb,  1.0 );
}
```

The [book of shaders](https://thebookofshaders.com/05/) visualisation and exercises for the sin function helped me visualise and come up with the solution.

Attached a screen clip of the result (lower quality due to stackoverflow's max size limit for images) 
[image: result]

Answer (score 2):

You could do something along the lines of

```
vec2 mySkewUv = vec2(vUv.x + vUv.y , vUv.y);
```

Comment: I used something like this: vec4 map = texture2D(uMap, vec2(vUv.x + vUv.y , vUv.y) ); but the effect was outside the bonds of the rendered area. I will update the question with more details

Comment: Well you need to apply additional transformation. For example just adding `vUv.x + vUv.y - 0.5` would center your skew. Try also uploading an image that is not a blob, but rather a grid, so it's more obvious what you want.

Comment: You are right! It has been bugging me all night! The -0.5 works for the centring. But what about rotating the effect?